# How can I localize and format ticks using D3 and Vue

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, momentjs

I'm using `vue-i18n` to format dates, like so:

```
const setDateTimeFormats = {
  short: {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
  },
};

export const dateTimeFormats = {
  en: setDateTimeFormats,
  ja: setDateTimeFormats,
};
```

And then calling it like this:

```
checkedOn() {
  return this.$d(moment(checkedOn), 'short');
},
```

But what I can't figure out is how to localize and format the ticks using D3 in the same project.

Here's the bit concerned with the ticks (which just shows the months from `Jan` to now:  `Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep`)

```
const x = scaleTime()
  .domain([moment('2020-01-01').toDate(), moment().toDate()])
  .range([0, width]);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'xaxis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(axisBottom(x).tickFormat(timeFormat('%b')));
```

Comment: If you want the full months' name use `.tickFormat(timeFormat('%B'))` instead of `.tickFormat(timeFormat('%b'))`.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, but that's not really what I want. I want to localize the months, based on locale (English, Japanese, etc.)

Comment: I see. Have a look at this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/805115ebaa574e771db1875a6d828949

Comment: I will. Thank you @GerardoFurtado